# Stock price MySQL database modeling?

Tags: mysql, database, stock

I have 5000 stocks that are updated Daily
Such as apple, google, twitter, facebook
Open close high low price datas are added

Will keeping all the stocks in a single database table in a flat file be a problem?

Or should i create a seperate table for every stock?

Concerning Speed and scalibilty

Thanks

Comment: Keep them in the same table, how'd you feel managing 5000 tables? If speed becomes an issue you can always look into [table partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html)

Comment: how many records do you put in daily ?

Comment: What is you table layout ?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you concern where you keep your data, or why would you wanna separate it ?
My advice :
Keep it in the same table. !